# How to create an ArrayList from an Array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I've got a list of files in an array. I want to enumerate those files, and remove specific files from it. Obviously I can't remove items from an array, so I want to use an `ArrayList`.
But the following doesn't work for me:

```
$temp = Get-ResourceFiles
$resourceFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($temp)
```

Where `$temp` is an Array.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I can't get that constructor to work either. This however seems to work:

```
# $temp = Get-ResourceFiles
$resourceFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
$resourceFiles.AddRange($temp)
```

You can also pass an integer in the constructor to set an initial capacity.

What do you mean when you say you want to enumerate the files? Why can't you just filter the wanted values into a fresh array?

**Edit:**

It seems that you can use the array constructor like this:

```
$resourceFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$someArray)
```

Note the comma. I believe what is happening is that when you call a .NET method, you always pass parameters as an array. PowerShell unpacks that array and passes it to the method as separate parameters. In this case, we don't want PowerShell to unpack the array; we want to pass the array as a single unit. Now, the comma operator creates arrays. So PowerShell unpacks the array, then we create the array again with the comma operator. I think that is what is going on.

Comment: @Mark, can you give some more information about how you want to decide what files to remove. Also, what does Get-ResourceFiles return?

Comment: I've got a text file with relative paths in it. After I've enumerated a dir, I want to check if it exists in the file, and if it doesn't exist, remove it from the list.
Get-ResourceFiles just returns a path as a string

Comment: @Mark, I would do something like this: "$newFiles = $oldFiles | where {Test-Path $_}". It might require some tweaking because it assumes all the paths are relative to the current directory.

Comment: @Mark, if you still have problems, post another stackoverflow question. Give plenty of details. Explain precisely what you want the code to do.

Comment: dan-gph - Please consider adding changing the line `New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$someArray)` to `$resourceFiles = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList(,$someArray)` to save someone else copying and pasting the line, making changes only to the right, and not the left, and wondering for an embarrassingly long amount of time what is missing :s

Comment: @user66001, fair enough. Done.

Answer (score 36):

Probably the shortest version:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$someArray
```

It is also faster because it does not call relatively expensive `New-Object`.

Comment: To get an instance this would actually be [System.Collections.ArrayList]$someArray = @() which works for me in Powershell 3.0, but I didn't check if powershell always uses ArrayList as the instance of array.

Comment: @npjohns PowerShell arrays are actually .NET arrays. (The `@().Add` method fails.) What's happening here is that PowerShell is not only casting, but also coercing the array to an `ArrayList`. You can confirm the type of an array like so: [`@().GetType().FullName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype)