# Shifting items in an array

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I am looking to shift the first two items in an array to the end.

For example, I simply want `160210` to become `021016`.

Is this doable within Powershell?

Thanks

Comment: [Convert the array to a list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/618675/3195526), remove the items, add them to the end, convert back to an array.

Comment: Is `160210` a string, or is it an array `1,6,0,2,1,0`?

Comment: It's actually a string but I would convert to array first so that I can control the individual characters

Comment: I will try that solution in the morning, thank you @PaulHicks

Comment: `$s = '160210'; $s.Substring(2) + $s.Substring(0, 2)`

Comment: You don't need to convert to an array or a list if you're working with strings. Every language has good support for doing this sort of thing with strings. Wheels are for going fast on, not for reinventing ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from an array of objects, the array slice notation `$array[a..b]` can do this for you.  Just concatenate two slices of the array - one from element 2 to the end, and one containing just the first two elements.

```
$array = 1,6,0,2,1,0
$newarray = $array[2..$array.length] + $array[0,1]
```

If you're starting from a string, another option is to use regex and the PowerShell `-replace` operator.

```
$string = "160210"
$newstring = $string -replace '(..)(.*)','$2$1'
```

Or simply use the .NET String `Substring()` method.

```
$newstring = $string.Substring(2) + $string.Substring(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could assign the contents of the array to 3 variables and shuffle them around like so:

```
$array = 1,6,0,2,1,0
$first,$second,$rest = $array
$array = $rest + $first + $second
```